# Converting JSON Date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, json, datatables

In SQL Server Database the date showing as **06-Feb-17 7:42:14 PM**.
But in Jquery DataTable this date is showing as **/Date(1486388669090)/**

What I have to do if I want to show the date exactly as **06-Feb-17 7:42:14 PM** format and **"dd/mm/yy"** format??

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Employees/LoadData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json"
                },
                "columns" : [
                        { "data": "EmployeeName", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "Department", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "Age", "autoWidth": true },
                        { "data": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
                        {
                            "data": "CreatedOn",// This is my date

                        }

                    ]
            });
 });
```

**Any appropriate help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Display Json Date in "dd/mm/yyyy" Format:**

```
    "columns" : [
                 { "data": "EmployeeName", "autoWidth": true },
                 { "data": "Department", "autoWidth": true },
                 { "data": "Age", "autoWidth": true },
                 { "data": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
                 {
                   "data": "CreatedOn",
                   "render": function(data) {
                                var dateString = data.substr(6);
                                var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
                                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                                var day = currentTime.getDate();
                                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

                                return (day.toString().length > 1 ? day : "0" + day) +
                                "/" +
                                (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) +
                                "/" +
                                year + " " + time;

                            }

                  }

    ]
```

And The date will will be displayed as: **06/02/2017**

**To Display Json Date exactly as "06-Feb-17 7:42:14 PM" Format:**

```
"columns" : [
                     { "data": "EmployeeName", "autoWidth": true },
                     { "data": "Department", "autoWidth": true },
                     { "data": "Age", "autoWidth": true },
                     { "data": "Gender", "autoWidth": true },
                     {
                       "data": "CreatedOn",
                       "render": function(data) {
                                var dateString = data.substr(6);
                                var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(dateString));
                                var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                                var day = currentTime.getDate();
                                var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                                var hour = currentTime.getHours();
                                var minute = currentTime.getMinutes();
                                var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

                                var localStandarHour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;

                        var time = (localStandarHour.toString().length > 1 ? localStandarHour : "0" + localStandarHour) + ":" + (minute.toString().length > 1 ? minute : "0" + minute) + ":"
                            + (seconds.toString().length > 1 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);


                                if (hour > 12 ) {
                                    time = time + " PM";
                                } else {
                                    time = time + " AM";
                                }


                                return (day.toString().length > 1 ? day : "0" + day) +
                                "/" +
                                (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) +
                                "/" +
                                year + " " + time;

                            }

                      }

        ]
```

And The date will will be displayed as: **06/02/2017 07:42:14 PM**

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date from epoch time to the time format you want. Try the MDN page for the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). The constructor can take in the epoch time and the functions like getYear, getMonth and so forth will give you the parts for your date string.