# how to fix - The breakpoint will not currently be hit. breakpoint set but not yet bound?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

i got the error like this ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgP4N.png)

help how to fix this error

Comment: Please refer below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC JsonResult Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726334/asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-date-format)

Comment: Exactly what you wnating..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070895/converting-json-date-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can make that using available date methods like this:

```
var d = new Date(1540995900000);
var date_string = d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + d.getUTCDate();
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a JavaScript function as following an just pass the date.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```